# Importing a PDF file with text into a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv, pdf

I'm a bit blocked here. I've been asked to put PDF files into a CSV file using Python. I've been looking on the internet and found this guide to do it at this adress :

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/03/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python/

There's a code written there explaining how to import PDF to CSV, I put the lines here :

```
import csv
import os

from miner_text_generator import extract_text_by_page


def export_as_csv(pdf_path, csv_path):
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]

    counter = 1
    with open(csv_path, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
        text = page[0:100]
        words = text.split()
        writer.writerow(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_path = 'w9.pdf'
    csv_path = 'w9.csv'
    export_as_csv(pdf_path, csv_path)
```

My problem now is that when I run it, it tells me that the module "miner_text_generator" is not found. I've tried to install it with pip but it doesn't work either. 
I'm working on Python 3.7

Do you guys have any ideas on how to fix that? Or has another way to do this? I can't use a API script or use a web based one, it must stay in my computer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import or install using `pip` because `miner_text_generator` is a python code written by the post author. You can create the .py file and save it in the same folder of your code, then the `import` will work:

```
# miner_text_generator.py

import io

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text

            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()

def extract_text(pdf_path):
    for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
        print(page)
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract_text('w9.pdf'))
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but this looks like a reasonable solution for me, as what the OP was trying to do was to import an example file made for the purpose of the blog post.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for Python 2.7. For the function page_interpreter.process_page(page) t results: TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'.